# Updating MySQL entries with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have a MySQL database with a table which has 4 columns (id, tvDate, tvCourse, tvRoom)

I have created a php page with connects to the database and returns the rows of the database table in an HTML table. I have added an edit link on each row to be able to edit the entries. The link calls up a php file with the row id (eg: edit.php?id=1) and shows the current content which you can then change.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqUlE.png)

Everything up to this point works fine but my problem is that when you change the content and click the update button I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id=1' at line 638

(same url edit.php?id=1) and the record does not get updated.

This is my code:

```
<?php include('includes/database.php'); ?>
<?php
    //Assign get variable
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    //Create select query
    $query ="SELECT * FROM tvdbase
             WHERE id = $id";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
        //Fetch object array
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $tvDate = $row['tvDate'];
            $tvCourse = $row['tvCourse'];
            $tvRoom = $row['tvRoom'];
        }
        $result->close();
    }
?>
<?php
    if($_POST){
        //Assign get variable
        $id = $_GET['id'];

        //Assign Variables
        $tvDate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tvDate']);
        $tvCourse = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tvCourse']);
        $tvRoom = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tvRoom']);

        //Create update
        $query = "UPDATE tvdbase
                  SET
                  tvDate='$tvDate',
                  tvCourse='$tvCourse',
                  tvRoom='$tvRoom',
                  WHERE id=$id
                  ";
        $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
        $msg="Updated";
        header('Location:index.php?msg='.urlencode($msg).'');
        exit;
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Edit Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>

         <form role="form" method="post" action="new.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">
                <label>Date</label>
                <input name="tvDate" type="text" value="<?php echo $tvDate; ?>" placeholder="Enter Date">
                <label>Course</label> 
                <input name="tvCourse" type="text" value="<?php echo $tvCourse; ?>" placeholder="Enter Course">
                <label>Room</label>
                <input name="tvRoom" type="text" value="<?php echo $tvRoom; ?>" placeholder="Enter Room">
            <input type="submit" value="Update Room" />
        </form>


  </body>
</html>
```

I suspect my problem is in the POST method somewhere. I'm still fairly new to PHP and mySQL so I appologise in advance for any bad coding :)

Comment: Check error in second `die()` It will tell you that `,` after `tvRoom` causes an error.

Comment: why are you using `mysql_real_escape_string` ???

Comment: Thanks, I update the post. The error I get now is: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id=1' at line 638

Comment: `mysql_*` functions do NOT intermix with the `mysqli_` API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the problems with your code.

You're mixing `mysql_` functions with the MySQLi_ API and they do not intermix.

This being all instances of `mysql_real_escape_string()` which need to be replaced with `mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['var'])`.

- Use a prepared statement instead, they're much safer.

Then you have a trailing comma in the UPDATE query's `WHERE` clause:

```
tvRoom='$tvRoom',
```

in here:

```
UPDATE tvdbase
  SET
  tvDate='$tvDate',
  tvCourse='$tvCourse',
  tvRoom='$tvRoom', <<< right there, remove it
  WHERE id=$id
```

Comment: Thanks Fred. I removed the trailing comma and it worked. I will replace the mysql_ functions as well.

Comment: @Alex However, I recommend you look into using a prepared statement instead. Here are a few links you can look into, but remember; you can't intermix `mysqli_` with PDO and vice-versa; here they are: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php - `mysqli_` prepared statement, connect with `mysqli_`. PDO prepared statement, connect with PDO.

Comment: I will definetely read up on it and use it. Still in the learning process. Thanks again, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

This is why I write my SELECT and UPDATE queries this way...

```
SELECT x
     , y
     , z
  FROM my_table;
```

It makes this kind of error almost impossible.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I wasn't :-)